# Lattice spring models vs. finite element models

Tags: finite-element, computational-physics

I am a beginning graduate student in the field of continuum mechanics. It is my understanding that most problems in this field are numerically solved via **finite element methods (FEM)**. However, I have also seen  papers where people are using **lattice spring models (LSM)** as their chosen numerical method.

I am not able to understand the difference between the two methods at a fundamental level as they both use finite elements for discretization. Can somebody please **help me compare/contrast** the two methods? I will also appreciate if somebody can point me to places where such comparisons might have been made. I tried to search for it, but couldn't find anything of much relevance on the internet.

Comment: What references have you read about the second method?

Comment: What's your application for using LSM? Is it for simulation hyperelastic or viscoelastic materials?

Comment: I apologize for my late response.
@nicoguaro Some of the papers I read are "Theoretical and computational modeling of self-oscillating polymer gels" by Yashin et al., "Deriving a lattice model for neo-Hookean solids from finite element methods" by Zhang, "A 3D distinct lattice spring model for elasticity and dynamic failure Gao-Feng" by Zhao et al., to name a few.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I do not have an application for the use of LSM per se. I am trying to simulate a hyperelastic material, and I originally thought that FEM is the way to go. But then I have seen papers on LSM too that are similar to FEM. However, I am not sure when does one use LSM over FEM.